# reading numbers from a website using openStream()

Tags: java, printwriter

For an assignment at school I am trying to read numbers from a website, sum them up and outputting them into a .txt file using openStream() and PrintWriter. My book gives me the following code, however the output file stays empty. I tried googling but I can't find the right answer using this method. Any ideas why it's not outputting the numbers? Thanks in advance.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

    URL pageLocation = new URL("http://www.math.com/");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    double total = 0;

    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        double value = input.nextDouble();
        output.printf("%15.2f\r\n", value);
        total += value;
    }

    output.printf("Total: %8.2f\r\n", total);

    input.close();
    output.close(); }
```

Comment: 1) As it stands, the code does not compile; brace is missing. 2) Have you already seen something about using try-catch? It might come handy to see any issue and close those input, output regardless of any exception. 3) You can check if you are getting the numbers and the sum correctly by system.out.println them.

Comment: Added a bracket my apologies. I am not getting the numbers or sum using the system.out.println either. Is input.hasNextDouble() not compatible with openStream maybe?

Comment: The program works, your logic to read doubles is not right.

Comment: What is the right logic?